# How do I send an Object and a file in a single HTTP request in java?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons

I need to send a java object and a file via HTTP in a single HTTP request. I am facing following issue:

I am using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient implementation for this and the problem is the servlet on the server side expects the multipart request as mentioned in the request and hence the Object which I send as a byte[] stream gets corrupted. If I just either file or object in a single request then this works fine.

Comment: Can you provide code example of your client sending code? Is the server-side is something that you can control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this tutorial: http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/ ?